# How to display and access individual key values with JADE

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug

When I loop through my object everything works and I can render all instances of it to the page. The problem is that I want to be able to select
a specific object key whereby every object that has that key renders its corresponding value to the page.

My code is below with a more clear explanation

**Mongoose.js schema**

```
var synthSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    patchName: String,
    synths: Object,

});

var SynthObject = mongoose.model('Synth', synthSchema);
```

**Node.js / Express code**

```
var synthPatch = new SynthObject({})

synthPatch.synths = [{
        synth_name: "blah blah",
        xpos: 12,
        ypos: 23
    },

    {
        synth_name: "more blah blah",
        xpos: 02,
        ypos: 238
    },

]



synthPatch.save(function (err, ok) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

});


app.get('/returnedData', function(req, res){
  SynthObject.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    res.render('returnedData', {
      title: 'Tasks index view',
      docs: docs
    });
  });
});
```

**JADE**

```
table.table

      each synth in docs
        tr
          td #{synth}

          ul
```

**The above code outputs ( from MongoDB)**

```
{ synths: [ 

    { synth_name: 'blah blah', xpos: 12, ypos: 23 }, 
    { synth_name: 'more blah blah', xpos: 2, ypos: 238 } 

  ],

 _id: 5352c4c46f5127d40e7ba8ec, __v: 0 

}
```

**Ok so far so good. The above code is just what I wanted, so lets loop through it and get keys and values**

**JADE code**

```
   each synthObject in docs
        tr
          each value, key in synthObject.synths
              each v, k in value
                  td #{k} #{v}
```

**Perfect...this outputs the following**

```
ypos 23 xpos 12 synth_name 'blah blah'
ypos 238    xpos 2  synth_name  'more blah blah'
```

However, now I run into my problem which is I want to select something like all of the **synth_name** from every object and output all of the synth_name *values*. I've tried a bunch of things but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.....for now

```
each synthObject in docs
      each item in synthObject.synths
              li #{item.synth_name} #{item.xpos} #{item.ypos}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on:
http://jade-lang.com/demo/

It works? Only difference i did was using 'docs' instead of 'synths' of given mongo data.

**Jade Input**

```
table.table
each synth in docs
    tr
    td #{synth.synth_name}
```

**Locals**

```
{ docs: [ 

    { synth_name: 'blah blah', xpos: 12, ypos: 23 }, 
    { synth_name: 'more blah blah', xpos: 2, ypos: 238 } 

  ],

 _id: "5352c4c46f5127d40e7ba8ec", __v: 0 

}
```

**results in:**

```
<table class="table">
  <tr></tr>
  <td>blah blah</td>
  <tr></tr>
  <td>more blah blah</td>
</table>
```

Comment: I have no idea why but that doesn't work for me. I get a blank page